# Bash Shell Scripting Errors: ./myDemo: 56: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: bash, syntax-error

Could someone take a look at this code and find out what's wrong with it?

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
    echo " Select one of the following options:"
    echo " d or D) Display today's date and time"
    echo " l or L) List the contents of the present working directory"
    echo " w or W) See who is logged in"
    echo " p or P) Print the present working directory"
    echo " a or A) List the contents of a specified directory"
    echo " b or B) Create a backup copy of an ordinary file"
    echo " q or Q) Quit this program"
    echo " Enter your option and hit <Enter>: \c"
    read option 
    case "$option" in
        d|D) date
             ;;
        l|L) ls $PWD
             ;;
        w|w) who
                 ;;
        p|P) pwd
             ;;
        a|A) echo "Please specify the directory and hit <Enter>: \c"
             read directory
                    if [ "$directory = "q" -o "Q" ]
                then
                    exit 0
                fi

                while [ ! -d "$directory" ]
                do
                        echo "Usage: "$directory" must be a directory."
                    echo "Re-enter the directory and hit <Enter>: \c"
                    read directory

                        if [ "$directory" = "q" -o "Q" ]
                        then    
                            exit 0

                        fi

                done
                    printf ls "$directory"

            ;;  
            b|B) echo "Please specify the ordinary file for backup and hit <Enter>: \c"
             read file
                if [ "$file" = "q" -o "Q" ]
                then
                    exit 0
                fi     

                while [ ! -f "$file" ]
                do
                    echo "Usage: \"$file\" must be an ordinary file."
                    echo "Re-enter the ordinary file for backup and hit <Enter>: \c"
                    read file
                        if [ "$file" = "q" -o "Q" ]
                        then
                            exit 0
                        fi              
                done
                    cp "$file" "$file.bkup"
                 ;;

        q|Q) exit 0
             ;;

    esac
    echo
done
exit 0
```

There are some syntax errors that I can't figure out. However I should note that on this unix system echo -e doesn't work (don't ask me why I don't know and I don't have any sort of permissions to change it and even if I wouldn't be allowed to)

<s>Bash Shell Scripting  Error: "./myDemo ./myDemo: line 62: syntax error near unexpected token `done' ./myDemo: line 62:`" [Edited]</s>

> **EDIT:** I fixed the while statement error, however now when I run the
>   script some things still aren't
>   working correctly.
>
> 1. It seems that in the b|B) switch statement
>
>    *cp $file $file.bkup* doesn't
>      actually copy the file to file.bkup ?
> 2. In the a|A) switch statement
>
> *ls "$directory"* doesn't print the directory listing for the user to see
>   ?

```
#!/bin/bash
while $TRUE
do
        echo " Select one of the following options:"
        echo " d or D) Display today's date and time"
        echo " l or L) List the contents of the present working directory"
        echo " w or W) See who is logged in"
        echo " p or P) Print the present working directory"
        echo " a or A) List the contents of a specified directory"
        echo " b or B) Create a backup copy of an ordinary file"
        echo " q or Q) Quit this program"
        echo " Enter your option and hit <Enter>: \c"
        read option
        case "$option" in
                d|D) date
                     ;;
                l|L) ls pwd
                     ;;
                w|w) who
                     ;;
                p|P) pwd
                     ;;
                a|A) echo "Please specify the directory and hit <Enter>: \c"
                     read directory
                        if [ ! -d "$directory"  ]
                        then
                                while [ ! -d "$directory" ]
                                do
                                        echo "Usage: "$directory" must be a directory."
                                        echo "Specify the directory and hit <Enter>: \c"
                                        read directory

                                        if [ "$directory" = "q" -o "Q" ]
                                        then
                                        exit 0

                                        elif [ -d "$directory" ]
                                        then
                                                ls "$directory"

                                        else
                                        continue
                                        fi
                                done
                        fi
                        ;;
                b|B) echo "Specify the ordinary file for backup and hit <Enter>: \c"
                     read file
                        if [ ! -f "$file" ]
                         then
                                while [ ! -f "$file" ]
                                do 
                                        echo "Usage: "$file" must be an ordinary file."
                                        echo "Specify the ordinary file for backup and hit <Enter>: \c"
                                        read file
                                        if [ "$file" = "q" -o "Q" ]
then
                                        exit 0
                                        elif [ -f "$file" ]
                                        then
                                        cp $file $file.bkup
                                        fi
                                done
                        fi
                        ;;

                q|Q) exit 0
                     ;;

        esac
        echo
done
exit 0
```

Another thing... is there an editor that I can use to auto-parse code? I.e something similar to NetBeans?

Comment: ./myDemo: 6: Syntax error: ")" unexpected (expecting "done")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `do` after the second `while`.  (The 'B' case; compare that against the 'A' case above it.)

I use gvim which will syntax highlight shell scripts, but I think you need to ask about editors as a separate question.

---

As for your modified question:
Your logic is broken in both the `A` and `B` cases: you need to pull the backup logic out of your if/while nesting... the `if` isn't actually doing anything for you.  Also, be sure to quote all your filenames so that spaces don't break your script.  Escape your nested quotes.  I believe you need a `-e` on the echo statements that use `\c`.

So do something more like:

```
b|B) echo -e "Specify the ordinary file for backup and hit <Enter>: \c"
    read file
    while [ ! -f "$file" ]
    do 
        echo "Usage: \"$file\" must be an ordinary file."
        echo -e "Specify the ordinary file for backup and hit <Enter>: \c"
        read file
        if [ "$file" = "q" -o "$file" = "Q" ]
        then
            exit 0
        fi
    done
    cp "$file" "$file.bkup"
    ;;
```

You'll need to do the same kind of change for the `A` case.

Comment: Thanks for the help retracile. And I'll have to give gvim a try.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `\c` working with `echo -e` in Bash. I always do `echo -n`.

Comment: Yeah, I generally use `-n` as well.  The `-e` though lets the various `\something`s work as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I am familiar with `-e` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems in the A) directory listing section.

1. The -o conjunction doesn't work like you think it does.  Should be:

   ```
               if [ "$directory" = "q" -o "$directory" = "Q" ]
   ```
2. Your outer "if" needs an "else" to handle the case when the directory given really is a directory right off the bat.

The B) backup section has the same two problems.  Fix those, and both command options will work.

Answer (score 2):

You've quoted the `$file` variable in most places, but in the `cp` command you don't. It should be:

```
cp "$file" "$file.bkup"
```

Some of your `echo` commands have "\c" at the end. I think that's specific to csh. Bash will just echo the characters "\" and "c" literally.

Your statement `while $TRUE` works by virtue of the variable being null or unset. If it gets set to some value, it will try to execute the contents as a command. If you want to do that type of infinite loop, it's typically done in Bash like this:

```
while true
```

where true is a shell builtin. Or:

```
while :
```

where the colon is a no-op that returns true. Of course there are other ways to accomplish the same thing.

In the `l|L)` case you probably want to do either:

```
ls
```

or

```
ls $PWD
```

the way you have it now, it's going to try to list the entry for a file named "pwd".

Both vim and nano can do syntax highlighting for Bash. If they are not already set up in `~/.nanorc` and `~/.vimrc` you can do these:

for nano:

```
nano -Y sh scriptname
```

For vim:

```
:syntax on
:set filetype=sh
```

Comment: Good catches on the `while $TRUE` and the `ls pwd`; I missed those in my answer.

Comment: The \c is not csh. Some of the old (pre-POSIX) shells used a trailing \c to suppress newlines, and the obsolete X/Open standard includes it. Try it on a Solaris box, using /usr/xpg4/bin/sh: echo "hello\c".

Answer (score 1):

1) you don't to use so many echoes.. to create a menu system, you can use cat here-document,eg

```
cat <<EOF
-------------------------------------------------------
Select one of the following options:
d or D) Display today's date and time
l or L) List the contents of the present working directory
w or W) See who is logged in
p or P) Print the present working directory
a or A) List the contents of a specified directory
b or B) Create a backup copy of an ordinary file
q or Q) Quit this program
--------------------------------------------------------
EOF
```

or even this will do

```
echo "-------------------------------------------------------
Select one of the following options:
d or D) Display today's date and time
l or L) List the contents of the present working directory
w or W) See who is logged in
p or P) Print the present working directory
a or A) List the contents of a specified directory
b or B) Create a backup copy of an ordinary file
q or Q) Quit this program
--------------------------------------------------------"
```

2) when asking use to choose an option, you can use read with -p, eg

```
read -p "Enter your option and hit <Enter>: " choice
```

3) printf is more portable than echo, therefore you should use it whenever possible.

Comment: I fixed all of the echo statements as per your directions. This is my error now: ./myDemo 
./myDemo: 6: Syntax error: ")" unexpected (expecting "done")